# DelegateCommand<object> is not beeing invoked

Tags: winrt-xaml, template10

I am using Template10.
I am utilizing a ListView.
The ViewModel needs to know the SelectedItems.
The SelectedItems should be passed as a parameter with a converter.
EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged" is tested working.
The converter is tested working.
DelegateCommand> SelectionChangedCommand is NOT working.
DelegateCommand of anything is NOT working (no string, no int - no nothing).
DelegateCommand SelectionChangedCommand is tested working.
Only DelegateCommands without parameter are working when
ListView -> EventTriggerBehavior -> InvokeCommandAction
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Let me start by saying that I use Cmd<T> constantly, so there's no reason to begin with the assumption that it does not work. The most likely thing is that the binding is out of scope.

Comment: This is the XAML part:

Comment: <Core:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                            InputConverter="{StaticResource SelectedItemsConverter}"
                            InputConverterParameter="{Binding AssociatedObject, ElementName=eventTriggerBehavior}" />

Comment: This is the converter:

Comment: public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return (parameter as ListView).SelectedItems;
        }

Comment: This is the command:

Comment: DelegateCommand<IList<object>> _SelectionChangedCommand;
        public DelegateCommand<IList<object>> 
            SelectionChangedCommand
           => _SelectionChangedCommand ?? (_SelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<IList<object>>
            ((o) =>
           {               if (o != null || o.Count > 0)
               {
                   foreach (var item in o)
                   {
                       if (!selectedItems.Contains(item)) selectedItems.Add(item as string);
                   }
               }
           }, (o) => true));

Comment: I have replaced <IList<object>> with simple <string> and <int>. The command is invoked only one time when the list initializes. If I don't use <T>, the command is invoked everytime the selection changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.
I changed the converter, so that it is returning a `List<string>` instead of `IList<object>`. It Looks like that the `DelegateCommand<T>` in the ViewModel did not match the `<T>` coming from the the converter/ListView although `ListView.SelectedItems` is `IList<object>`. Furthermore I changed the concept, now the Delete Buttons gets the list of selected items which saves some Code, Events and doubled lists.